# YouTube feed API (JSON-P) returning invalid JS

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, jsonp, feed

Has anyone come across YouTube's feeds API returning invlaid JavaScript over JSON-P, due to instances of `\n`? Example:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/M-nbBMcOzjk/comments?max-results=50&callback=jQuery191018773837325938192_1378827386276&_=1378827386277&format=json

It's wrapped in the call to the callback, as you'd expect for JSON-P, but breaks my code due to the line breaks. You would have thought YT would have catered for this.

There's no pertinent code to show in this question, as the code isn't the problem - it's the response that, when executed via the callback, causes the error.

Am I missing a param I can pass or something?

(Sidenote: I could load genuine XML over CORS instead but this doesn't work for IE8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your URL used is wrong. Should it not be "&alt=json" instead of "&format=json". Clicking your link returns XML instead of JSON.

Comment: Actually `format=json` was a guess by me to solve the problem. Didn't know about `alt=json` - thanks a lot.